# How to use fluentd output_kafka plugin?

Tags: apache-kafka, fluentd

I have installed output_kafka plugin for my fluentd by command "gem install fluent-plugin-kafka".

but when i start fluentd service, i got following error message in log file:

2012-11-09 18:18:39 +0800: temporarily failed to flush the buffer, next retry will be at 2012-11-09 18:52:46 +0800. error="uninitialized constant *Kafka::Message*" instance=69952455476860

It seems that output_kafka.rb can not found module Kafka or class Message, so how can i fix it?

Comment: I also have errors with it and kafka 0.7. I wonder if this fluentd pluging was abandonned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Kaz, Fluentd committer. This sounds like a bug of fluent-plugin-kafka. Could you report the bug from here, with your environment description?

> https://github.com/kiyoto/fluent-plugin-kafka/issues

Once you've reported, i'll take a look at it. Thanks -K